# GraphQL Schema Definition Error

Tags: node.js, graphql

I am trying to define GraphQL schema like this:

> type Obj {
>       id: Int
>       0_100: Int
>   }

But it gives following exception.

> 'GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found Int "0"',

How can I define attribute starting with numeric, -, + signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the regexp for names in GraphQL: `/[_A-Za-z][_0-9A-Za-z]*/`. Anything that does not match is not allowed.

Sample URL:
http://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Names

Answer (score 2):

Numerical parameter names do not work in GraphQL.

You can probably prefix it with a string like `_0_100`, but it's fairly unusual and I'd recommend against it. Consider using words to name your parameters instead.